# Trying to return values in Table A that do not exist in Table B

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables for inventory tracking. TABLE_A is for the actual records, TABLE_B is for that record's history with regards to it's location; moved from Building 1 to Building 2, etc.

Most of the records in TABLE_A are in TABLE_B, but there are a few that are in TABLE_A that are not in TABLE_B. I'm trying to write a query to only get which records in TABLE_A do not exist in TABLE_B.

```
TABLE_A.Item_ID
101
102
103
104
105

TABLE_B.Item_ID
101
103
104
```

I thought doing the following would work, but it's not.

```
select a.Item_ID
from TABLE_A a 
left outer join TABLE_B b on (a.Item_ID = b.Item_ID)
where b.Item_ID is null
order by a.Item_ID desc
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Though there is other way for it but my point is your query should work as per your expectations. What makes you say it's not working ?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: I have changed the tags to [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) and [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info). [PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) is a programming language and [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer) is a commercial desktop application, and neither is related to the question.

Comment: what is the expected output for your sample data

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the `MINUS` set operator:

```
select item_id from table_a
minus
select item_id from table_b
```